# Question on finding solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have trouble solving the following ODE, I am wondering if I can get any hint or help

The ODE I am facing is following
$$\frac{\mu x}{y'(x)}=-A-x+\eta y(x)$$
where $A, \mu,  \eta$ are all constant. I tried to find an integration factor, which I failed to find one. I am attempting to find an explicit solution and I can't get one either.

Any help or hint will be extremely appreciated. Explicit form will be better.

Thank you so much

Comment: Did the answer resolve your issues on this problem?

Comment: @Amzoti yes, I tried linear function and it fits well..though I don't know if it's the unique solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try linear function as the solution to your ODE

Comment: @Amzoti sure, basically if y is linear in x, then $\frac{x}{y'(x)}$ is of order 1 for x, which should be the same as the order of RHS if y is linear. So the rest is just to resolve the coefficient for y, let's leave that to OP